# Eliminar un objeto de una lista y agregar por medio de un checkbox en vuejs si se tilda o no

Tags: vue.js

Hola chicos tengo una lista de objetos la cual se compone de la siguiente manera:

```
                    new Vue({
                            el: '#app',
                            data: {
                                checkedAnio: [2017,2018,2019,2020],
                                total_mensual:  {"2017":{"8":8402118,"12":16805365},"2018":{"1":3380427,"2":3383808,"6":1450000,"7":1741365,"8":11577539,"9":2588845,"10":3000000,"12":14868336},"2019":{"2":1594755,"3":11707602,"5":9460500,"9":6080000,"10":11900000,"11":18216520,"12":9779550},"2020":{"2":1443190,"3":44647800,"4":12288093,"8":19644587,"11":-342845469,"12":910439192}},
                                filterLista: {"2017":{"8":8402118,"12":16805365},"2018":{"1":3380427,"2":3383808,"6":1450000,"7":1741365,"8":11577539,"9":2588845,"10":3000000,"12":14868336},"2019":{"2":1594755,"3":11707602,"5":9460500,"9":6080000,"10":11900000,"11":18216520,"12":9779550},"2020":{"2":1443190,"3":44647800,"4":12288093,"8":19644587,"11":-342845469,"12":910439192}},                             entidades: {"10836904":"LUIS IGNACIO SALAZAR GALLEGOS","76035258":"Bruening Industrial","76122564":"Sociedad Comercializadora de Excedentes SpA","76122571":"Lampa SpA","76131794":"Sociadad comercializadora de excedentes Ferro Velh","76467560":"Inversiones Islam Ltda","76675405":"EQUIPOS Y MAQUINARIAS PINCHEIRA SPA","76829879":"Consorcio San Alberto de las Condes","76833156":"RECICLAJES REM SPA","76849049":"Comercializadora Alejandro Contreras SpA","76860599":"ACEROS DEL SUR S.A.","76898325":"RG Chile SpA","76914652":"Logistica Global Group SpA","76985375":"NUEVA LUZ DESECHOS LIMITADA","77078359":"ACEROS AMERICA SPA","77241295":"PATRICIA CORTES GUZMAN SPA","77418580":"Mantos Copper S.A","77612130":"SOC. COM. RECMETAL CIA. LTDA.","79587210":"Minera escondida limitada","92176000":"GERDAU AZA S.A.","96777810":"Polytex S.A","96935140":"SIDERVAL SA","99526550":"Ingenieria y montaje ferrovial s.a"},
                                pendientes: {"2017":{"8":{"99526550":8402118},"12":{"99526550":16805365}},"2018":{"1":{"99526550":3380427},"2":{"99526550":3383808},"6":{"76467560":1450000},"7":{"76675405":1741365},"8":{"76675405":11577539},"9":{"96777810":2588845},"10":{"76898325":3000000},"12":{"76035258":14868336}},"2019":{"2":{"76035258":1594755},"3":{"76675405":11707602},"5":{"79587210":9460500},"9":{"10836904":6080000},"10":{"76849049":11900000},"11":{"76914652":18216520},"12":{"76122571":9779550}},"2020":{"2":{"76122564":658878,"76675405":784312},"3":{"76122571":6746300,"77418580":37901500},"4":{"76860599":12288093},"8":{"76122571":3519040,"76829879":8986547,"76985375":7139000},"11":{"76833156":0,"79587210":-342845469,"96935140":0},"12":{"76131794":99960000,"76833156":43282120,"77078359":54621000,"77241295":110610500,"77612130":53818420,"79587210":534178302,"92176000":6156500,"96935140":7812350}}}
                            },
                            computed: {
                              listaMensual(){
                                return this.filterLista
                              }
                            },
                            methods: {
                               arrayRemove(anio) {
                                  delete this.listaMensual[anio]
                               }
                            }
                    })

            

            <div v-for="(meses, ano) in total_mensual">
                                        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                                            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input js-periodos mr-2" checked="" :value="ano"
                                                   v-model="checkedAnio"
                                                   :id="'anio_'+ ano"
                                                   @change="arrayRemove(ano)">
                                            <span class="custom-control-label">{{ ano }}</span>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
```

Ya el checkbox viene cargado con los años al destildar alguno de ellos elimina el índice por año de la variable **listaMensual** pero si lo tildo nuevamente quisiera que esta lista de dicho año que fue eliminada se agregara nuevamente de la variable **total_mensual** como por ejemplo:

> {"2017":{"8":8402118,"12":16805365}}

Esta seria la lista:

```
<table class="table card-table table-vcenter text-nowrap table-hover" id="t-mayor">

                    <thead>

                    <tr>
                        <th style="background-color: white">Razón Social</th>
                        <template v-for="(meses, ano) in listaMensual">
                            <template v-for="(total_mes, mes) in meses">
                                <th class="js-data-" style="background-color: white">{{ printMonth(mes) }}  {{ ano  }}</th>
                            </template>
                        </template>
                        <th style="background-color: white">Totales</th>
                    </tr>

                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                    <template v-for="(raz_soc, rut) in entidades">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="background-color: white">@{{ printName(rut) }}</td>
                            <template v-for="(meses, ano) in listaMensual">
                                <template v-for="(total_mes, mes) in meses">
                                    <td v-if="pendientes[ano][mes]">@{{ pendientes[ano][mes][rut] ? pendientes[ano][mes][rut] : 0 }}</td>
                                </template>
                            </template>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </template>

                    </tbody>

                    <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="background-color: #f5f5f5"></td>


                    </tr>
                    </tfoot>

                </table>
```

He buscado la forma de hacerlo pero en todas e fallado, use filtre pero me devolvía siempre errores. Si alguno en la comunidad puede ayudar a entender como hacerlo se lo agradecería.

Comment: No deberias tener un elemento mas en la lista, que sea la marca de mostrar o no mostrar??? si lo eliminas, como seleccionas de vuelta para que vuelva a aparecer, proque al eliminarlo deberia desaparecer...

Comment: Si te fijas hay dos variables en data una que filtra y hace la lista con un método computado y otra que esta la original donde no se elimina.

Comment: @gbianchi de igual manera actualice mi pregunta y coloque la lista del html que me faltaba, creo que asi se entiende un poco mejor lo que quiero

Comment: Creo que deberías trabajarlos como un Array completamente en vez de objeto, esto te permitiría emplear métodos básicos como push o slice para eliminar elementos de dicha lista. Tampoco es necesario un computed que solo retorna el mismo elemento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Lo que se busca:

En general los `checkbox` pueden darte ese comportamiento de agregar y sacar de una lista en automatico con `v-model` sin tener que implementar cosas extra como en el siguiente ejemplo:

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            fruits: ['', '', '', ''],
            fruitsSelected: [],
        }
    }
})
```

```css
/* no es necesario, solo aumentamos el tamaño de letra*/
div, p {
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <div v-for="fruit in fruits">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" :value="fruit" v-model="fruitsSelected" :id="fruit">
            {{ fruit }}
        </label>
    </div>
    <p> Selected {{fruitsSelected}}</p>
</div>
```

Si quieres que todas las opciones estén seleccionadas por *default* necesitas llenar la variable que usaste en tu `v-model`, si es vacía `[]` quiere decir que no se ha seleccoinado nada, si tiene más de un elemento significa que se considera que por defecto ya se han seleccionado varios elementos pero Vue se encarga se saber cuales:

> Puedes usar `mounted()` para asignar el valor por completo a tu variable y que todo quede selecionado.

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            fruits: ['', '', '', ''],
            fruitsSelected: [],
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.fruitsSelected = this.fruits
    }
})
```

```css
/* no es necesario, solo aumentamos el tamaño de letra*/
div, p {
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <div v-for="fruit in fruits">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" :value="fruit" v-model="fruitsSelected" :id="fruit">
            {{ fruit }}
        </label>
    </div>
    <p> Selected {{fruitsSelected}}</p>
</div>
```

## Solución al problema en particular:

Cuando dejas toda la carga al `checkbox` y requieres que todos estén seleccionados puedes usar:

En Vue, `data` suele ser una función, pero en tu caso es un atributo, cambiando eso y simplificando un poco el código para un ejemplo minimo:

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            totalMensual: {
                "2017": {
                    "8": 8402118,
                    "12": 16805365
                },
                "2018": {
                    "1": 3380427,
                    "2": 3383808,
                    "6": 1450000,
                    "7": 1741365,
                    "8": 11577539,
                    "9": 2588845,
                    "10": 3000000,
                    "12": 14868336
                },
                "2019": {
                    "2": 1594755,
                    "3": 11707602,
                    "5": 9460500,
                    "9": 6080000,
                    "10": 11900000,
                    "11": 18216520,
                    "12": 9779550
                },
                "2020": {
                    "2": 1443190,
                    "3": 44647800,
                    "4": 12288093,
                    "8": 19644587,
                    "11": -342845469,
                    "12": 910439192
                }
            },
            filterLista: [],
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.filterLista = Object.entries(this.totalMensual).map(([key, value]) => ({
            [key]: value
        }))
    },
    computed: {
        sortedList() {
            return this.filterLista.sort((a, b) => Object.keys(a)[0] - Object.keys(b)[0])
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <div v-for="(meses, ano) in totalMensual">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" :value="{[ano]: meses}" v-model="filterLista" :id="ano">
            {{ ano }}
        </label>
    </div>
    {{sortedList}}
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente la probé aquí internamente y funciona, mil gracias

Comment: Sabes que note no si sea posible cuando se agregue a la filterLista se agregue de menor a mayor? de acuerdo al año

Comment: Puedes usar `computed`, y ahí hacer un ordenamiento. La pregunta ha sido actualizada para ese caso. Mi implementación **no es lo más óptimo** pero puedes anexarlo a la deuda técnica de tu proyecto.

Comment: Gracias man tendré que leer un poco mas sobre vue o javascript veo que aun estoy en panales, aun me falta rehacer la suma por filas y colocar un total al final de cada una, investigare como hacero.

Comment: Pero eso será por cada fila en una tabla, también puede suceder que si se quita un año el total disminuya o aumente según el filtro del checkbox. Agradecido