# ¿Cómo solucionar el error se marcan todos los checkbox en vue?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

Hola tengo un formulario simple en vue, creo mi data en vue para retornar la informacion en un v-for, para así crear mis checkbox, este es mi código:

```
    return{
          alguna_vez: ['Un Ataque Cardiado', 'Cirujía Cardiaca', 'Marcapasos', 'Ninguno'],  
          nueSintomas:{
                    chkAlguna_vez: '',
                    chksintomas: '',
                    chkotros_aspectos: '',
                },
```

Y aquí esta mi v-for:

```
<div v-for="(item,index) in alguna_vez " :key="index">
       <input type="checkbox" id="" v-model="nueSintomas.chkAlguna_vez" :value="item" id>
             {{item}}
 </div>
```

El problema es que al momento de dar check a uno, se marcan todos y viceversa, ayuda porfavor

Comment: En tu `v-model` haces referencia a `nueSintomas.chkAlguna_vez`, verifica que está propiedad sea un array. Puedes revisar [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/441406/101864) para un ejemplo mínimo

Comment: Lo tengo así, ya edite mi pregunta, por favor revísa si esta bien

Comment: Solo cambia a esto `chkAlguna_vez: []` en tu data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

la propiedad nueSintomas.chkAlguna_vez debe ser un arreglo
puedes probar asi:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    nueSintomas:{
       "chkAlguna_vez": []
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Gracias, me funciono